# How to make Sudoku solver with backtracking algorithm go back?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sudoku, backtracking

This weekend I worked on a Sudoku Solver ([Ruby quiz](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz43.html)) based on a backtracking algorithm. The sudoku is loaded in an array `sudoku_arr` of 81 integers (9x9 grid) where 0's are empty spots. There is a `valid?` method which checks if the `sudoku_arr` can be a valid sudoku.

The [official backtracking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms#Backtracking) goes like this: try value on next empty spot, check if it is valid sudoku, if not increase value by 1 (upto 9), if valid go on and try first value on next spot, if not increase value of previous 0.

Hereby we have to keep track of the previous array, and that is where I am going wrong and I am not sure if it can be solved. The part of my code below that is not working is the `solve_by_increasing_value_previous_index` in the `SudokuSolver` class. Here's the code:

```
require 'pp'

sudoku_str = "
+-------+-------+-------+
| _ 6 _ | 1 _ 4 | _ 5 _ |
| _ _ 8 | 3 _ 5 | 6 _ _ |
| 2 _ _ | _ _ _ | _ _ 1 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 8 _ _ | 4 _ 7 | _ _ 6 |
| _ _ 6 | _ _ _ | 3 _ _ |
| 7 _ _ | 9 _ 1 | _ _ 4 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 5 _ _ | _ _ _ | _ _ 2 |
| _ _ 7 | 2 _ 6 | 9 _ _ |
| _ 4 _ | 5 _ 8 | _ 7 _ |
+-------+-------+-------+"

class SudokuException < StandardError
  attr_reader :sudoku_arr
  def initialize(message, sudoku_arr)
    super(message)
    @sudoku_arr = sudoku_arr
  end
end

class Sudoku

  attr_accessor :sudoku_arr, 
                :index_of_tried_value,
                :tried_value

  def initialize(sudoku_arr, index_of_tried_value, tried_value)
    @sudoku_arr = sudoku_arr
    @index_of_tried_value = index_of_tried_value
    @tried_value = tried_value
  end

  def rows_valid?
    rows_have_unique_values?(@sudoku_arr)
  end

  def columns_valid?
    rows_have_unique_values?(@sudoku_arr.each_slice(9).to_a.transpose.flatten!)
  end

  def squares_valid?
    tmp_a = @sudoku_arr.each_slice(3).to_a

    rows_have_unique_values?(
    (tmp_a[0] << tmp_a[3]  << tmp_a[6]  << tmp_a[1]  << tmp_a[4]  << tmp_a[7]  <<
    tmp_a[2]  << tmp_a[5]  << tmp_a[8]  << tmp_a[9]  << tmp_a[12] << tmp_a[15] <<
    tmp_a[10] << tmp_a[13] << tmp_a[16] << tmp_a[11] << tmp_a[14] << tmp_a[17] <<
    tmp_a[18] << tmp_a[21] << tmp_a[24] << tmp_a[19] << tmp_a[22] << tmp_a[25] <<
    tmp_a[20] << tmp_a[23] << tmp_a[26]).flatten!)
  end

  def valid?
    rows_valid? && columns_valid? && squares_valid?
  end

  def rows_have_unique_values?(arr)
    (arr[0,9]- [0]).uniq.size == (arr[0,9]- [0]).size &&
    (arr[9,9]- [0]).uniq.size == (arr[9,9]- [0]).size && 
    (arr[18,9]-[0]).uniq.size == (arr[18,9]-[0]).size && 
    (arr[27,9]-[0]).uniq.size == (arr[27,9]-[0]).size && 
    (arr[36,9]-[0]).uniq.size == (arr[36,9]-[0]).size && 
    (arr[45,9]-[0]).uniq.size == (arr[45,9]-[0]).size && 
    (arr[54,9]-[0]).uniq.size == (arr[54,9]-[0]).size && 
    (arr[63,9]-[0]).uniq.size == (arr[63,9]-[0]).size && 
    (arr[72,9]-[0]).uniq.size == (arr[72,9]-[0]).size 
  end

end


class SudokuSolver

  attr_accessor :sudoku_arr, 
                :indeces_of_zeroes

  def initialize(str)
    @sudoku_arr = str.gsub(/[|\+\-\s]/,"").gsub(/_/,'0').split(//).map(&:to_i)
    @indeces_of_zeroes = []
    @sudoku_arr.each_with_index { |e,index| @indeces_of_zeroes << index if e.zero? }
  end

  def solve
    sudoku_arr = @sudoku_arr
    try_index = @indeces_of_zeroes[0]
    try_value = 1
    sudoku = Sudoku.new(sudoku_arr, try_index, try_value)
    solve_by_increasing_value(sudoku)
  end

  def solve_by_increasing_value(sudoku)

    if sudoku.tried_value < 10
      sudoku.sudoku_arr[sudoku.index_of_tried_value] = sudoku.tried_value
      if sudoku.valid?
        pp "increasing_index..."
        solve_by_increasing_index(sudoku)
      else
        pp "increasing_value..."
        sudoku.tried_value += 1
        solve_by_increasing_value(sudoku)
      end
    else
      pp "Increasing previous index..."
      solve_by_increasing_value_previous_index(sudoku)
    end
  end

  def solve_by_increasing_index(sudoku)
    if sudoku.sudoku_arr.index(0).nil? 
      raise SudokuException(sudoku.sudoku_arr.each_slice(9)), "Sudoku is solved."
    end

    sudoku.index_of_tried_value = sudoku.sudoku_arr.index(0)
    sudoku.tried_value = 1

    solve_by_increasing_value(sudoku)
  end

  def solve_by_increasing_value_previous_index(sudoku)
    # Find tried index and get the one before it
    tried_index = sudoku.index_of_tried_value
    previous_index = indeces_of_zeroes[indeces_of_zeroes.index(tried_index)-1]

    # Setup previous Sudoku so we can go back further if necessary:

    # Set tried index back to zero
    sudoku.sudoku_arr[tried_index] = 0
    # Set previous index
    sudoku.index_of_tried_value = previous_index
    # Set previous value at index
    sudoku.tried_value = sudoku.sudoku_arr[previous_index]
    pp previous_index
    pp sudoku.tried_value
    # TODO Throw exception if we go too far back (i.e., before first index) since Sudoku is unsolvable

    # Continue business as usual by increasing the value of the previous index
    solve_by_increasing_value(sudoku)
  end

end

sudoku_solver = SudokuSolver.new(sudoku_str)
sudoku_solver.solve
```

Unfortunately the code does not backtrack to the beginning. The code prints:

> "increasing_index..." 
>   "increasing_value..." 
>   "increasing_value..."
>   "increasing_value..." 
>   "increasing_value..." 
>   "increasing_value..."
>   "increasing_value..." 
>   "increasing_value..." 
>   "increasing_value..." 
>   "Increasing previous index..." 
>   16 
>   2

in a loop till it throws a `SystemStackError` because the stack level is too deep.

What happens is that the "backtracking" does not go further back than one index. When the `solve_by_increasing_value_previous_index` goes to the previous index it takes the previous value there. In this case it is a 2, but the 2 is not working and we should therefore decrease it to a 1 and continue, and if that does not work, discard the 2 and make it a 0 again and go back further.

Unfortunately I do not see an easy way to implement this algorithm. <sub>(What I thought of was a `@too_much_looping` variable that gets incremented when the `solve_by_increasing_value_previous_index` gets called, and after 81 times gets a reset. But this only helps with going back one more time, we cannot loop back to the beginning.</sub> \

I hope someone can provide me with some help! General code comments are very welcome too, I have a suspicion this is not 100% idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet waded through your code, but the backtracking algorithm boils down to the following:

```
int solve(char board[81]) {
    int i, c;
    if (!is_valid(board)) return 0;
    c = first_empty_cell(board);
    if (c<0) return 1; /* board is full */
    for (i=1; i<=9; i++) {
        board[c] = i;
        if (solve(board)) return 1;
    }
    board[c] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

This is a recursive function that tries each value from `1` to `9` in the first empty cell it finds (returned by `first_empty_cell()`). If none of these values leads to a solution, then you must be on a dead branch of the search tree, so the cell in question can be reset to zero (or whatever value you use to indicate an unfilled cell).

Of course, there are a lot of other things you could do to make your software arrive at a solution faster, but as far as backtracking goes, that's all there is to it.

---

### Addendum:

OK, I'm wading through your code now. It looks like you're storing `index_of_tried_value` as an attribute of the sudoku grid. That won't work. You need to store this value in a local variable of the solver routine so it can be pushed onto the stack and recovered when you backtrack down the search tree.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. My question is how do you go further back after resetting a value to 0? I mean, you go to the previous value and then increase it? Or wait... You continue for the first value and increase that by one?! That seems right*... How do you remember where you were in the branch? Two variables (index and value)? /edit, it doesn't since you cannot discard the whole branch... You should go back and increase the value on the previous index by one. And if that doesn't work, the one before that. How do you keep track?

Comment: @user2609980 It's all done on the stack. The line `board[c] = 0;` restores the value of the current cell to "unfilled" and returns a value of zero (="not solved") to the `for` loop in the calling iteration of `solve()`, where the previous unfilled cell was being considered. If all the tests on the previous cell fail, then the previous cell is reset to zero too, and a new value is tried for the cell before that. And so on...

Comment: Hi your answer helped me a lot to identify the problem. I don't think the problem was storing the index_of_tried_value on the sudoku since I have only once instance. But the problem was that I did not increase the value with one while backtracking. By adding a +1 the code seems to work: `# Set previous value at index
    sudoku.tried_value = sudoku.sudoku_arr[previous_index] + 1`, unfortunately it does not make the end of the Sudoku because of a `stack level to deep error`, do you see a way to solve this. PS I accept your answer since you basically answered it. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks :-) If you do backtracking properly, your call stack can only ever reach a depth of 81 levels and will never overflow. It sounds like you're still using a global variable to store your position in the search tree, which is wrong. You *have* to use a local variable inside the search routine (like `i` in the above example code) if you want it to work properly. (Well, unless you create an array of 81 elements to store the search progress in every cell, I suppose. But why bother with that?)

Comment: Using your much simpler algorithm it works! I see the SudokuException. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is an algo called "Dancing links" invented by knuth, which can be applied in Sudoku.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links

Soduko problem can be solved by exact cover problem. Here is the article
http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/dancing-color.ps.gz

here is my code to solve exact cover problem, it can also solve sudoku
and the backtracing part is in dlx()

```
const int INF = 0x3f3f3f3f;
const int T = 9;
const int N = T*T*T+10;
const int M = T*T*T*4+T*T*4+10;
int id;
int L[M],R[M],U[M],D[M];
int ANS[N],SUM[N],COL[M],ROW[M],H[N];


struct Dancing_links
{
    Dancing_links() {}
    Dancing_links(int n,int m)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
        {
            SUM[i] = 0;
            L[i+1] = D[i] = U[i] = i;
            R[i]=i+1;
        }
        L[m+1]=R[m]=0,L[0]=m,id=m+1;
        clr(H,-1);
    }

    void remove(int c)
    {
        L[R[c]] = L[c];
        R[L[c]] = R[c];
        for(int i=D[c]; i!=c; i=D[i])
            for(int j=R[i]; j!=i; j=R[j])
            {
                U[D[j]] = U[j];
                D[U[j]] = D[j];
                SUM[COL[j]]--;
            }
    }

    void resume(int c)
    {
        for(int i=U[c]; i!=c; i=U[i])
            for(int j=L[i]; j!=i; j=L[j])
            {
                U[D[j]] = D[U[j]] = j;
                SUM[COL[j]]++;
            }
        L[R[c]] = R[L[c]] = c;
    }

    void add(int r,int c)
    {
        ROW[id] = r,COL[id] = c;
        SUM[c]++;
        D[id] = D[c],U[D[c]] = id,U[id] = c,D[c] = id;

        if(H[r] < 0)
            H[r] = L[id] = R[id] = id;
        else
            R[id] = R[H[r]],L[R[H[r]]] = id,L[id] = H[r],R[H[r]] = id;
        id++;
    }

    int dlx(int k)
    {
        if(R[0] == 0)
        {
            /*output the answer*/return k;
        }

        int s=INF,c;
        for(int i=R[0]; i; i=R[i])
            if(SUM[i] < s)
                s=SUM[c=i];

        remove(c);
        for(int r=D[c]; r!=c; r=D[r])
        {
            ANS[k] = ROW[r];
            for(int j=R[r]; j!=r; j=R[j])   remove(COL[j]);

            int tmp = dlx(k+1);
            if(tmp != -1) return tmp; //delete if multipal answer is needed

            for(int j=L[r]; j!=r; j=L[j])   resume(COL[j]);
        }
        resume(c);
        return -1;
    }
};
```