# Sudoku Solver in SML with Backtracking

Tags: sml, sudoku, backtracking, smlnj

I'm working on creating a Sudoku Solver with SML/NJ. I've got all of the functions in place to actually manipulate the input data (check for legality of rows, forcing the empty spaces, etc) but I'm having trouble with the backtracking part.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108258/how-to-make-sudoku-solver-with-backtracking-algorithm-go-back) but I'm confused on how to implement it in SML.

Note that a board is input as a list of lists that represent the numbers in each row, 0 for an unknown spot

```
[[0,0,0, 2,6,0, 7,0,1],
[6,8,0, 0,7,0, 0,9,0],
[1,9,0, 0,0,4, 5,0,0],

[8,2,0, 1,0,0, 0,4,0],
[0,0,4, 6,0,2, 9,0,0],
[0,5,0, 0,0,3, 0,2,8],

[0,0,9, 3,0,0, 0,7,4],
[0,4,0, 0,5,0, 0,3,6],
[7,0,3, 0,1,8, 0,0,0]]
```

Here is my (edited) `solve` function.

```
exception Sudoku;
fun solve board =
  let fun solve' board k =
    (* k is the row we are working on, so if it's 9, we SHOULD be done *)
    if k = 9 then board else
    let
      (* get row k from the board *)
      val row = (List.nth (board, k));

      fun trySpot number col =
        (* if number >= 10, raise an exception to backtrack *)
        if number > (length row) then raise Sudoku
        (* if col = 9, raise an exception to backtrack *)
        else if col = 9 then raise Sudoku
        (* if row[col] is not a zero, move to next col *)
        else if not (List.nth(row, col) = 0) then trySpot number (col + 1)
        (* row doesn't contain this num already *)
        else if length (List.filter (fn x => x = number) row) = 0 then
          let
            (* build the new row and board and check if legal (this works fine) *)
            val newRow = delete(col + 1, (insertAtPos row number col));
            val newBoard = delete(k + 1, (insertAtPos board newRow k));
            val isLegal = checkLegal newBoard;
          in
            (* if legal, keep solving with new board as base *)
            if isLegal then
              solve' (force newBoard) 0
              handle Sudoku => solve' (force board) (k + 1)
            (* not legal, try with next num *)
            else trySpot (number + 1) col
          end
        (* row already has this number, skipping *)
        else trySpot (number + 1) col
    in
      (* if board is complete and legal we're done *)
      if completedBoard board andalso checkLegal board then board
      (* if row has a zero then try a spot *)
      else if (zeroInList row) then trySpot 1 0
      (* otherwise move to next row *)
      else solve' (force board) (k + 1)
    end
  in
    (* initial solve *)
    solve' (force board) 0
  end;
```

Calling `solve` on the sample data above returns the following lists

```
[[4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1],
[6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3],
[1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2],

[8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7],
[3,1,4,6,8,2,9,0,0],
[0,5,0,0,0,3,0,2,8],

[0,0,9,3,0,0,0,7,4],
[2,4,0,0,5,0,0,3,6],
[7,0,3,0,1,8,0,0,0]]
```

Now this is partially correct. The first four rows look to be fully correct based on an online sudoku solver I used to check, but it gets messed up on the 5th row. I presume it's because it's not able to backtrack all the way.

The only place it "backs up" is on this line

```
handle Sudoku => solve' (force board) (k + 1)
```

This tells it to just try solving the old board (without the new number) but this is preventing it from backtracking more than one step (I think). How could this be accomplished?

If anyone is curious to see the full code, you can find it [here.](http://pastebin.com/KXc5w1wb)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The book "Introduction to Programming using SML" by Hansen and Rischel contains an example of a backtracking algorithm to solve the 8 queens problem implemented using exceptions. I was able to modify their code to get knight tours without too much difficulty. It might give you some ideas (although nowadays I would be more likely to use options rather than exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I'll take a look

Comment: @JohnColeman, I took a look their implementation, and tried to modify my  solve function to implement the backtracking with exceptions. It works to an extent, but I'm not sure how to make it go back further into the decision tree. Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas right now, I've never done much with Sudoku (not even by hand -- I much prefer crossword puzzles and cryptograms). I just thought that the book would give you some ideas. If I have time later on this week, I'll give it some thought but the next few days are busy for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have gotten my solve function to work with all of the cases I've tried. The trick was to keep track of a list of illegal numbers for the spot we were working on. The solver will now skip over these numbers, and backtrack if it can't find a path forward.

```
exception Sudoku;
(* solves a soduku board input that gives a list of lists representing the rows of a board (0 for unknown spaces) *)
fun solve board = 
  let fun solve' board row illegalNums = 
    (* if we are on row 9 and board is complete/legal, we are done *)
    if row = 9 andalso completedBoard board andalso checkLegal board then board else
    (* if we are on row 9 but the board is not complete/legal, throw an exception to backtrack *)
    if row = 9 then raise Sudoku else 
    let
      (* get the current row we are working on *)
      val cRow = (List.nth (board, row));

      (* trys a row[col] on the board with a certain number *)
      fun trySpot num cRow col =
        (* if number >= 10, raise an exception to backtrack *)
        if num > 9 then raise Sudoku
        (* if row[col] is not a 0, try next col *)
        else if not (List.nth (cRow, col) = 0) then trySpot num cRow (col + 1)
        (* if we know that the number we are on isn't allowed, skip to next number *)
        else if length (List.filter (fn x=> x = num) illegalNums) > 0 then trySpot (num + 1) cRow col
        (* if row already has this number, skip to next number *)
        else if length (List.filter (fn x=> x = num) cRow) > 0 then trySpot (num + 1) cRow col
        (* if col already has this number, skip to next number *)
        else if length (List.filter (fn x=> x = num) (List.nth((rowsToCols board), col))) > 0 then trySpot (num + 1) cRow col
        else 
          let
            (* make our new row and board *)
            val newRow = delete(col + 1, (insertAtPos cRow num col));
            val newBoard = delete(row + 1, (insertAtPos board newRow row));
          in
            (* if new board is legal, continue solving *)
            if checkLegal newBoard then
              solve' (force newBoard) 0 []
              (* handle any exceptions by adding the number to our list of illegal numbers, thereby backtracking *)
              handle Sudoku => solve' (force board) row (illegalNums@[num])
            (* if new board is not legal, try next number *)
            else trySpot (num + 1) cRow col
          end
    in
      (* if board is completed and legal, return board *)
      if completedBoard board andalso checkLegal board then board
      (* if current row has at least one 0, try a number in that row (beginning at col 1) *)
      else if (zeroInList cRow) then trySpot 1 cRow 0
      (* else, skip to next row and solve *)
      else solve' (force board) (row + 1) []
    end
  in
    (* initial solve *)
    solve' (force board) 0 []
  end;
```

The harder boards can take quite a while to fully solve, but every one I've tested eventually gets there. I'm sure there are a ton of optimizations I can do in my code, so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm glad that you got it to work. Perhaps you could post it on Code Review to get more feedback. I think that one improvement would be to get rid of exceptions in favor of options. Returning `NONE` replaces raising an exception and pattern matching against `NONE` replaces `handle`. I read that in O'CAML at least using options is much quicker than raising exceptions since it doesn't involve unwinding the call stack. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7952625/4996248

Comment: Reading up on this a bit more, I'm not sure if  there would be a time gain for using options, though I still think that options are conceptually clearer than exceptions. One thing that might make a difference is to replace lists by `vectors` -for your board representation - your board has fixed size so you don't need the ability of lists to grow, and the `O(1)` access time for vectors should probably be a gain.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for the suggestions. I'll take a look at options instead of exceptions. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with lists. This is an assignment for a class, and our professor would like us to use plain old lists. I might still mess around and see if vectors make an improvement though, so thanks for the idea!

Comment: Sounds like you have a good professor. The only way to really learn a language is to use it for problems which are both nontrivial and interesting.